# phpmyadmin wamp mysql cannot declare variable in procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, wamp

I have unsloved problem when I try to create a stored procedure following code below
but it shows error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near at line 5

and this is my code Thanks for advice.

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE item_page_insert(IN cid INT, IN it_title VARCHAR(200), IN tumbnail VARCHAR(300), IN publish_date DATE, IN cover_set VARCHAR(20), IN pcontent TEXT, IN status INT) MODIFIES SQL DATA   
 BEGIN 
DECLARE mpid INT;
SELECT max(pid)+1 INTO mpid
FROM tbpage;
INSERT INTO tbite(cid, pid, it_title, tumbnail, publish_date, cover_set)
VALUES(cid,
       mpid,
       it_title,
       tumbnail,
       publish_date,
       cover_set);
INSERT INTO tbpage(pid, pcontent, set_date, status)
VALUES(mpid,
       pcontent,
       now(),
       status); END;

 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

it should be
    DECLARE mpid AS INT;

try that one